# Do we want to do a 'promotion'?

Tags: discussion

Eg pick some of the top most valuable questions and share them on social media, news sites and the like. It'll drive awareness, get some people some gold badges, and even bring in more visitors.

Answer (score 2):

I think as a site or a community we are not eager to do a promotion, also seeing the lack of activity on this question.
But let that not stop those members of us who are active on other social media to promote TSE by linking or even just mentioning us.

Find a question you like (or even hate) and link to that on an other site/forum/twitter/whatever and you will do that promotion.
You know 'any attention is good attention'.